# Click anywhere on card to go to next step

Tags: usability, website-design, experience, click

[Will it make better experience if user clicks on any part of card and go to next level.As of now user has to click on Company name to open next level,What do you suggest

[image]

Comment: There's too many call to actions on your card. What am I supposed to click on? Company name? "more"? "connect" That wifi-looking underlined bit? The star? The image?

Comment: main interaction is going to next page,it is now happening after clicking the company name. that wifi symbol is actually categories incase user has to change category

Answer (score 1):

I would do some user testing and study analytics to see if users click anywhere in the card expecting to open it or to realise they come back after clicking by accident.

It depends on how close the card is to being [a tile](https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html#grid-lists-content).

It makes sense **if the whole card has a main action and its size is small enough to be considered a tile**. If it has bigger size and several actions then keep each action to its button/link/icon, which seems to be your case. Also in your example consider opening the next level in both Company name and logo.

[image]

Comment: but there would be very less chance of miss click on web right.

Comment: I agree there can be miss clicks on mobile..Presently user has to move cursor on top of company name and click.

Comment: I would use it (an actually use it) for simple cards with a very evident main action and not much extra ones. But in your case you have feed, categories, users, read more, connect, favorite... which I guess redirect the user somewhere else. What is the chance that the user wanted to click any of those but missed it and got redirected to the Company next level? So in the actual layout Im not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the card to trigger the interaction is not obvious - there is no affordance. People will need to either be educated about this interaction or will discover it by accident (or trial and error).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance

> An affordance is the possibility of an action on an object or environment. Additional meanings have developed, largely a result of misinterpretations. The original definition in psychology includes all actions that are physically possible. When the concept was applied to design, it started also referring to only those action possibilities which one is aware of.

It would be better to provide an explicit button or link to trigger the behaviour you need.